# Problems with flash player after update, it does not work, jump of flash player from 11 to 24

Tags: 16.04, updates, firefox, flash, 16.10

After an system update this message appears

[image]

After click in "run this action now" button
flash was not working

---

**You could too have problem instaling it from the official adobe website**

for instance in my case for Ubuntu I selected APT version downloads and after have installed it, flash did not work, I had to uninstall it via Synaptic.
[image]


Flash installed but

[image]

Flash is not working

[image]

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score -1):

for facility , you can install Synaptic from the software center,
and search

> adobe-flashplugin

and uninstall it, there you will realize that it automatic will uninstall one or more packages too, continue or accept.
After that , search from Synaptic

> flashplugin-installer

And install it.

I had a problem with ***adobe-flashplugin***. I was installing it because found this [information](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html). I have to say that above is a option for you all that have similars problems and  that adobe-flashplugin is the oficial way to install it.
[image]

Comment: hello pal, how you say then yesterday I suffered that temporary server glitch, because i did had installed adobe-flashplugin but it was not working, the only way to check it is trying one more time.

Comment: I removed my comment above, since it was partly based on a misconception. In any case, (the latest) `adobe-flashplugin` works fine for me, and even if you had some problem with it it's not a general truth that it's not working. (Did you possibly forget to restart the browser?) Actually, `adobe-flashplugin` installs precisely the same plugin for Firefox as `flashplugin-installer`, and it does so from the same source (the Canonical Partner repository).

Comment: ok pal , but I did not forget to restart the browser, because it itself asked me to restart